# How to fix table is mutating exception while updating the table after insert using trigger in oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have made a trigger to update the table "SchemeComp" row while inserting a new row. I am inserting multiple/bulk row at a time but it throws an exception and the row does not get inserted. This is the exception I am getting:

```
Error report -
ORA-04091: table ABC009.SchemeComp is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "ABCS009.TrCreateParentChildRelation", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ABCS009.TrCreateParentChildRelation' `
```

This is my Query for trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TrCreateParentChildRelation"
AFTER INSERT ON "SchemeComp"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW."ParentComponentCode" IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE "SchemeComp" sc1
    SET sc1."ParentId" = (
        SELECT sc2."Id"
        FROM "SchemeComp" sc2
        WHERE sc1."ParentComponentCode" = sc2."ComponentCode"
          AND sc1."SchemeId" = sc2."SchemeId"
    )
    WHERE sc1."ParentComponentCode" IS NOT NULL
      AND sc1."SchemeId" = :NEW."SchemeId";
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Below is my insert query, I am running both the insert query at once.

```
INSERT INTO "SchemeComp" ("ParentId", "ComponentCode", "ParentComponentCode", "ComponentName", "SchemeId", "EntryDate", "IsActive", "CreatedBy", "IP")
VALUES (null, 'B', null, 'Tribal Area Sub Plan', '0R55', SYSTIMESTAMP, '1', 'BANKADMIN002', '::1');

INSERT INTO "SchemeComp" ("ParentId", "ComponentCode", "ParentComponentCode", "ComponentName", "SchemeId", "EntryDate", "IsActive", "CreatedBy", "IP")
VALUES (null, 'B.1', 'B', 'Recurring', '0R55', SYSTIMESTAMP, '1', 'BANKADMIN002', '::1');
```

Comment: The DBMS is telling you that it is in the process of changing the table, so you cannot query the table, because the result would not be deterministic, as the rows may get inserted in arbitrary order and would thus influence the query result unpredictably. What are you trying to do anyway? Why does inserting a new row infuence existing rows? And, in order to understand your table better: What do the rows represent? What is/are the table's unique key(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *directly* `update` (or select values from) table into which you're inserting rows because it is - as error says - *mutating*.

But, if you rewrite trigger so that you first select desired value and then update it, then it should be OK. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TrCreateParentChildRelation"
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON "SchemeComp"
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_parentid  "SchemeComp"."ParentId"%TYPE;
BEGIN
   IF :NEW."ParentComponentCode" IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      SELECT sc2."Id"
        INTO l_parentid
        FROM "SchemeComp" sc2
       WHERE     sc2."ComponentCode" = :new."ParentComponentCode"
             AND sc2."SchemeId" = :new."SchemeId";

      :new."ParentId" := l_parentid;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I see this got accepted and am surprised that this works. It shouldn't matter whether to have the trigger before each row or after. The table is mutating because of an insert. A single insert statement can insert many rows in arbitrary order, so we must not query the table, as the result will not be deterministic. Maybe this happens to work, as long as we only insert single rows, and fails otherwise. I don't know.

Comment: Ah! Silly me, @Thorsten! I didn't even notice that it is about the **same** table! Instead, I was paying attention to mixed letter case. You're right, that won't work unless single row is inserted. We'll see what Turing says after some testing. If it turns out that this answer is useless, I'll remove it.

Comment: @Littlefoot this is working good! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.